# Gracefully exit Java application if JRE version less than intended JRE to run

Tags: java

This might sound dumb. Bear with me. I am working on a java application which is intended to run in JRE 1.6 or above.

I am using Netbeans and I set the 'Java Platform' information in Project Properties as JDK 1.6.

I came across a scenario where if it ran in a machine which has lower version (1.4.2), then I am getting the following error message.

```
[dinesh@dinesh-PC mypgms]$ java -jar MyApp.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: myApp.Main (unrecognized class file version)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.7rh)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.7rh)
[dinesh@dinesh-PC mypgms]$
```

I have a check to get the java version with the following manner

```
static double getJavaVersion() {
        String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        int pos = version.indexOf('.');
        pos = version.indexOf('.', pos + 1);
        return Double.parseDouble(version.substring(0, pos));
    }
```

I doubted whether this method will be called or not. In `main()`, I am calling this method which is the first statement, and I got the above error. As expected, It seems like loading class itself causing a problem in lower JRE version.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        double javaVersion = getJavaVersion();
        System.out.println("Java Version : " + javaVersion);
        if (javaVersion < 1.6) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please install JRE 1.6 or higher version.", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
            return;
        }
       // More code 

}
```

How should I gracefully show an error message to the user when the application launched from lower versions of JRE ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is writing a class which is compiled to the lowest possible version you think of.  You would then use it to do your check for the JVM version.  If it passes, you would have to use dynamic class loading (`Class.forName` for example) to load the "actual" class you want to run your application, this could be configured.  As a wild idea of the top of my head

Comment: @MadProgrammer: not a "wild" idea - that solution works fine. I have been using that for a long tim enow.

Comment: following @MadProgrammer's idea, I think perhaps you can avoid the dynamic class loading if you manually add the wrapper class to the jar.  I think the JRE checks each class individually (I know the version is on the class level) and a jar file is really just a zip file.

Comment: @sharonbn: you have to use reflection. Because any class that is directly referenced from the main class will be loaded during startup - but if that dependent class can't be loaded neither can the main class.

Comment: it will also have to compiled.... you're right

Comment: @sharonbn I think the dynamic class loading process would allow you to inject the "launcher" class into your Jar, as it would need to be compiled at a lower API level then the rest of your classes, so you want to try and keep them separate, at least that's what I was thinking, haven't really tested it ;)

Comment: just another reason why we need dynamic type system in Java (like they have in C#)

Comment: @MadProgrammer : I have tried the way your have explained and it is working fine. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Dinesh Well that makes a pleasant surprise

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of distributing your application as a jar, you can package it with a startup script that can perform the necessary pre-requisite checks. 
I think a windows batch and *nix shell script will cover most of your needs.

Comment: Many exe wrappers can double check the JVM version before launching the Jar as well on Windows, which is generally cleaner then a batch file (IMHO)